# android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. ...... run time error in titanium app

Tags: javascript, android, cursor, titanium, expandablelistview

I use a large ExpandableListView with sometimes more then 500 groups. Internally android has opened a cursor for each group. This leads to the following exceptions:

```
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=741 (# cursors opened by this proc=741) run time error in titanium app
```

Is there a way to circumvent this crash? My only idea is to build a custom list that behaves like an expandable list. I don't like that approach because it is high effort. Any ideas?

Thanks + Best regards
FL

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening so many cursors, try opening just one cursor, but keeping pointers to the positions which form the Group Items and the Child Items.

Comment: The CursorTreeAdapter opens the cursor automatically when the group is expanded. I want all the groups to be initially expanded. So all cursor are opened automaticall be the CursorTreeAdapter. This leads to the exception anyway.